# Can we call multiple ko.applyBindings method in one page?

Tags: knockout.js, javascript

Why below code is not working as expected? When I call only one ko.applyBindings method it works.
Can we call multiple ko.applyBindings method in one page?

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
The name is <span data-bind="text: personName"></span>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myViewModel = {
        personName: 'Bob',
        personAge: 123
    };

var ViewModel=function(first, last)
{
this.firstName=ko.observable(first);
this.lastName=ko.observable(last);
this.fullName=ko.pureComputed(function()
{
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Hello", "World"));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  But you need to call `ko.applyBindings` with the element you wish to apply bindings to.  Here's a sample borrowing from the code you posted:

HTML:

```
<div id="model1">
    <p>First name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2> </div>

<div id="model2">
    The name is <span data-bind="text: personName"></span>,
    age is <span data-bind="text: personAge"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myViewModel = {
    personName: 'Bob',
    personAge: 123
};

var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName=ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName=ko.observable(last);
    this.fullName=ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('model2'));
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Hello", "World"), document.getElementById('model1'));
```

**Note** that I changed your `ko.pureComputed` to `ko.computed`, as there is no pureComputed in the knockout 3 runtime I was using.  Were you using an extension?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krpqzwqd/

Comment: `ko.pureComputed` is part of knockout 3.2.